# Is it possible to search multiple columns for multiple values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a doctor looking at surgical activity in a DataFrame that has 450,000 records and 129 fields or columns. Each row describes a patient admission to hospital, and the columns describe the operation codes and diagnosis codes for the patient.

```py
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 452883 entries, 0 to 452882
Columns: 129 entries, fyear to opertn_24Type
dtypes: float64(5), int64(14), object(110)
memory usage: 445.7+ MB
```

There are 24 operation columns for each row. I want to search in the operation columns (1-24) for the codes for pituitary surgery `"B041" and "B012"`, to identify all patients who have had surgery for a pituitary tumor.

I am a total python beginner and have tried using iloc to describe the range of columns (1-24) which appear starting at position 72 in the list of columns but couldn't get it to work.
I am quite happy searching for individual values eg `"B041"` in a single column using
`df["OPERTN_01"] == "B041"`
but would ideally like to search multiple columns (all the surgical columns 1-24) more efficiently.
I tried searching the whole dataframe using

`test = df[df.isin(["B041", "B012"])]`

but that just returns the entire dataframe with null values.

So I have a few questions.

1. How do I identify integer positions (iloc numbers) for columns in a large dataframe of 129 columns? I just listed them and counted them to get the first surgical column ("OPERTN_01") at position 72 — there must be an easier way.
2. What's the best way to slice a dataframe to select records with multiple values from multiple columns?

Comment: Would be nice to a sample input and output in the text form?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean, its difficult to display the 129 columns in this software.

Comment: you don't have to show the whole dataframe. Only the sample that can be used to reproduce the problem. Please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: lets say in one of the 29 columns returns a true value, do you want to return the entire dataframe where that row is true? if there are 5 rows and only row 5 in columns 1-27 contain your value then return that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `.iloc` and create a boolean for you to filter by:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["John","Deep","Julia","Kate","Sandy"], 
                     "result_1" : np.random.randint(5,15,5),
                    "result_2" : np.random.randint(5,15,5) })
print(df)

       A  result_1  result_2
0   John        11         5
1   Deep         6        11
2  Julia         7         6
3   Kate         8         9
4  Sandy         8        10
```

Next we need to find your intended values in the selected columns:

```
df.iloc[:,1:27].isin([11,10])
```

this returns:

```
   result_1  result_2
0      True     False
1     False      True
2     False     False
3     False     False
4     False      True
```

From the above, we need to slice our original dataframe by the rows where any value is true (if I've understood you correctly).

For this we can use `np.where()` with `.loc`:

```
df.loc[np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].isin([11,10])==True)[0]]

       A  result_1  result_2
0   John        11         5
1   Deep         6        11
4  Sandy         8        10
```

From here it's a simple task to extract your unique IDs.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**:

Let's say you are looking for `eg_col` in your dataframe's columns. Then, you can find its index within the columns using:

```
df.columns.tolist().index('eg_col')
```

**Answer 2**:

In your example, if you know the name of the last surgical column (let's say it's called `OPERTN_24`, you can slice those columns using:

```
df_op = df.loc[:, 'OPERTN_01':'OPERTN_24']
```

Continuing from that, we can look for values of `'B041', 'B012'` in `df_surg` as you tried: `df_op.isin['B041', 'B012']` which will return the boolean value for all dataframe entries.

To extract, for example, only those rows where at least one of our `'B041'` values comes up, we select those rows with:

```
df.index[df_surg.isin(['B041', 'B012']).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: answer 1 -  good stuff but how about all 24 of the OPERTN columns or a list of all column numbers ? and using ``` df.index[df_surg.isin['B041', 'B012'].any(axis=1)]``` gives ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-d9bc3bd75fa2> in <module>
----> 1 df.index[df_op.isin['B041', 'B012'].any(axis=1)]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Re: error, my mistake, parentheses were missing: `df.index[df_op.isin(['B041', 'B012']).any(axis=1)]`. 

You can extract the columns containing `'OPERTN'` by using the `.str.match` method (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)), and their corresponding `iloc`-type indices with Numpy's `where` method: `np.where(df.columns.str.match('OPERTN') == True)`.

Comment: Many thanks, Have learnt a lot from that though I still can't get the Jupyter Notebook cell to copy into this forum software despite reading the suggestion by  Grayrigel above.